# Ubuntu title bar application name shortened

Tags: ubuntu

I am running ubuntu 16.04 and have enabled the "menu always displayed" option. However, the menu covers half of the original application name ("Firefox" instead of "Firefox Web Browser").

[image: screenshot]

**Is there any Ubuntu guru who knows how to hack this and stop the Menu covering the active programs name?**